# Moving the background image when we hit the end of it

Tags: html, background

I am actually making a small website for my company, but i'm not good into HTML.

I am placing an image in background.
But i want some think special.

When someone is reading the site and go down, the image doesn't move.
But when we hit the end of this image's background, the image's background follow the user to the down.

I know the code for making it fixe, and making it following.

But i don't know how to

```
IMG go Fixe;
IF (End of IMG) {IMG go Follow;}.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a background of an image that has text over it and scrolls/moves with the page when the user scrolls down. If this is what you are asking, and please correct me if I am wrong, then some CSS will do the trick!

Since you are new to HTML, I will assume that you don't know CSS but you know HTML. So create a new file called 'stylesheet.css' inside of the same folder as your webpage. Between the head tags in your HTML, add the following line of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Now, in your HTML body, put the image inside and give it an id of "background". Do this by writing:

```
<div id="background">
    <code for image>
</div>
```

Now open your .css file and add the following code:

```
#background{
    opacity: 0.7;
    position:fixed;
}
```

The opacity property makes sure people can see the text in front of it, and the position property anchors it to a position on the browser window.

For future reference, W3Schools.com is a great site for beginner web programmers.

Hope I helped, Justin

Comment: Not exatly, but thanks you to help me.

My problem is localised into the "background-attachment", but thanks you, now i know how to use css into html.

I'm looking for a "background-attachment : scroll", who become "background-attachment : fixe" when we hit the end of the background-image".